# Dynamics CRM 2013 : Notes rendering issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have this issue on a Dynamics CRM 2013 server: there is a problem with the rendering of notes (on any form) see the picture bellow.
The configuration of the Server is :
Windows Server 2012 | SQL Server 2012 | Dynamics CRM 2013 with SP1

Anyone had this problem before ? Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Have you changed any fields on the form? Could you have changed the Notes field by mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the language pack didn't have the same build number as the CRM.
So I installed the SP1 for the language pack and it solved the problem.